# fscanf Returning Unexpected Result

Tags: c

I have been trying out some file io and have written the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char stuff [80];
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("hello.cheese", "w+");
    fprintf(file, "%s", "cheese");
    fscanf(file, "%s", stuff);
    printf("%s", stuff);
    fprintf(file, "\n%s", stuff);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

All this does is put ^A in the file (next line underneath cheese) and print nothing.

Comment: Add `fflush(file)` before and after the `fscanf()` statement.    Did you bother to read the documentation for the `+` modes on `fopen()`?

Comment: 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from `fscanf()` to assure the operation as successful.  3) when reading from a file (fscanf()) that was just written to, the 'file pointer' will be at the end of the file.  before reading anything from the file, use something like: `fseek()` to move the file pointer, in this case, back to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read closely [fopen description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html), especially

> When a file is opened with update mode ( '+' as the second or third character in the mode argument), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, the application shall ensure that output is not directly followed by input without an intervening call to fflush() or to a file positioning function ( fseek(), fsetpos(), or rewind()), and input is not directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

You used 'w+' mode, which allows reading and writing, but did not flush, nor rewind file pointer after write.

As a side note, Your code could use some error checking (`NULL != file`).